# Remove characters from a function result

Tags: python, string

My function gives me a result (example 17012) and I need to turn that into (17)

Without the function it works:

```
abc = "17034"
abc = abc[:-3]
print abc
(result 17)
```

But how to do it with this:?

```
c4dnum = c4d.GetC4DVersion()
print c4dnum (this is 17034)
```

I'm new to python, do you need to convert this into a string first?

Comment: what did this show print c4dnum[:2] if it show error then you may need to convert it in to string

Comment: "do you need to convert this into a string first?" - why don't you try for yourself and see ?

Answer (score 0):

`GetC4DVersion()` returns an int so your print would be : `print ("this is " + c4dnum)`.